# OpenEMR Installation error Step 3

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to install OpenEMR in a windows 10 VM for a college project.  I have downloaded the latest XAMPP package for MySQL and PHP.  I keep getting this error when trying to install any help greatly appreciated

[image: error image]

Comment: what exactly is not perfectly clear with the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

Two options to consider here:

1. Install the XAMPP/OpenEMR package instead (has XAMPP/PHP is pre-configured for OpenEMR):
   https://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/OpenEMR_5.0.0_XAMPP_Package_Installation
2. If instead still wish to try to get native XAMPP to work with OpenEMR (is not easy), ensure you have the proper PHP settings:
   https://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#What_are_the_correct_PHP_settings_.28can_be_found_in_the_php.ini_file.29.3F